# UnknownHostException using Inetadress.getbyName

Tags: java

I am trying to get the hostname of my server ipaddress using below commands,

```
InetAddress serverdetails=InetAddress.getbyName(<ip-address>)
String serverhostname=serverdetails.gethostname();
```

But i'm getting **unknownhostexception.**

note:i am able to ping the serverip address using command prompt.

**Code**:

```
private class PingTarget extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean reachable = InetAddress.getByName(
                    ConnectionPropHolder.TargetMachine).isReachable(5);
            if (reachable) {
                UploadtoServer();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using, please?

Comment: I'd say catch it and consider it unreachable. If the host is unknown, it is obviously unreachable. If you **know** that it should be up and running, check if hostname is given correctly.

Comment: Ya i did it. But GetByName is only throughing exception right.so i am not able to catch the name

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadocs for `getByName(String)`, this exception is thrown if

> no IP address for the host could be found, or if a scope_id was specified for a global IPv6 address.

The "no host could be found" applies if the string is a hostname that cannot be resolved to an IP address, or if it is a malformed IPv4 or IPv6 address in string form.

The exception message will tell you which of the above causes applies, and it will probably tell you what string was trying to parse or lookup.  (If it doesn't tell you the latter, it is trivial to capture and print out the value of `ConnectionPropHolder.TargetMachine` in the exception handler.)